# Expression to match human readable print format

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with a 3rd party database that stores strings in a human readable format.  I need to translate these strings into network addresses.  The form is as follows:

`"X on Y (from Z) in session N"`

X = printer name (1 to many words)
Y = Server name (1 word)
Z = Client name (1 word)
N = integer
"on Y" is optional
if " on " is part of the printer name then I expect this to fail.

If the string contains "on Y" the result should be:  `@"\\ServerName\PrinterName"`

Otherwise:  `@"\\ClientName\PrinterName"`

Can you provide something to perform the task?  It'd be great to avoid Regex because I find them to be difficult to maintain.  However, if it's the best tool for this job then that's fine.

Sample:

`"MY PRINTER NAME on MyServer (from MyWorkstation) in session 2"`

This should be transformed to:  `\\MyServer\My Printer Name`

Sample 2:

`"MY PRINTER NAME (from MyWorkstation) in session 2"`

This should be transformed to:  `\\MyWorkstation\My Printer Name`

Comment: Where are you stuck with this?

Comment: I don't think your question is that clear. Could you give a full sample string and expected result? Maybe the code you have so far?

Comment: "PRINTER ON MY DESK (from X) in session 1" - How can you tell if that is a printer named "PRINTER ON MY DESK" or a printer named "PRINTER" and a server named "MY DESK"?

Comment: @mbeckish I doubt it is possible.  I can't change the way the system stores the strings (its 3rd party).

Comment: Are the printer names always uppercase?

Comment: Then you are out of luck, unless you want to add more assumptions to your post, like maybe it is an acceptable risk to assume no printer or server will have "ON" in the name?

Comment: No, sometimes they are sometimes not.

Comment: You never answered the original question - where are you stuck?  Don't make us guess whether you are looking for a simple but flawed solution to get you started, or if you have figured out almost everything but just need help with a tricky part.

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that does not require regex.  I know I can solve this with regex myself, but I want to avoid it.  However, I don't know if that's possible.  That's what I am asking.

Comment: Where are you stuck with the non-regex solution?  You must have at least been able to come up with the solution @Belogix suggested, right?  How much farther did you get, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, you say you have a regex solution - how would you solve the "PRINTER ON MY DESK (from X) in session 1" case with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree that regexes often end up being hard to maintain, especially if you don't know the ins and outs, but your case seems like an encyclopedic example on when to use regexes and catch groups.

Something like the following:

```
var match = Regex.Match(
   YOUR_STRING,
   @"(?<printer>.+?)(\s+on\s+(?<server>.+?))?\s+\(from\s+(?<client>.+?)\s*\)");
var result = String.Format(
   @"\\{0}\{1}",
   match.Groups["server"].Success
    ? match.Groups["server"].Value
    : match.Groups["client"].Value,
   match.Groups["printer"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this:

```
// humanString = "MY PRINTER NAME on MyServer (from MyWorkstation) in session 2"    
var location = humanString.Contains(" on ") ? "MyServer" : "MyWorkstation";
```

Comment: This really only works if I already have "MyServer" and "MyWorkstation" extracted from the string.  Plus I don't see how this helps me obtain the printer information which is required to obtain the end result.

Comment: This was showing that other than using RegEx you would have to parse your string. So, you could do `Contains` that tells you whether it is Server/Workstation. You could then do `IndexOf` to get location of " on " etc... Lots of ways and just highlighting the simple. RegEx is way to go though = @decPL answer. But you wanted to avoid so showing a simple alternative.